# Exporting non-default-constructible classes with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost-python

How do I export a non-default-constructible class with Boost.Python?

This code:

```
class EventHandle {
 public:
  EventHandle() = delete;
  EventHandle(boost::shared_ptr<EventManager> const& em): event_manager_(em) {}
  EventHandle(EventHandle const&) = delete;
  ~EventHandle();
  shared_ptr<EventManager> event_manager_;
}
class_<EventHandle, noncopyable,
  init<boost::shared_ptr<EventManager> const&>>("EventHandle")
```

gives the following error:

```
/opt/local/include/boost/python/pointee.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::python::detail::pointee_impl<false>::apply<boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&> >':
/opt/local/include/boost/python/pointee.hpp:38:1:   instantiated from 'boost::python::pointee<boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&> >'
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:31:   instantiated from 'boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_convertible<boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&>*, EventHandle*>, boost::mpl::identity<boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&> >, boost::python::pointee<boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&> > >'
/opt/local/include/boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp:179:13:   instantiated from 'boost::python::objects::class_metadata<EventHandle, boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable, boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&>, boost::python::detail::not_specified>'
/opt/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:174:42:   instantiated from 'boost::python::class_<EventHandle, boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable, boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&> >::id_vector'
/opt/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:627:55:   instantiated from 'boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::class_(const char*, const char*) [with W = EventHandle, X1 = boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable, X2 = boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&>, X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]'
/Users/neil/nn/src/core/python_event.cc:21:66:   instantiated from here
/opt/local/include/boost/python/pointee.hpp:28:44: error: no type named 'element_type' in 'class boost::python::init<const boost::shared_ptr<EventManager>&>'
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/distributions.dir/core/python_event.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/distributions.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/distributions.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [distributions] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to expose the constructor with `init<...>`. For example, for a constructor taking two ints:

```
class_<MyClass>("MyClass", init<int, int>())
    ....
```

Note that you need to place the `init` inside the `class_` parameters rather than in a separate `.def()` call, or Boost will assume you have a default constructor.

See [the tutorial section about constructors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.constructors).

Edit: 
For your code, try:

```
class_<EventHandle, noncopyable>("EventHandle", 
    init<boost::shared_ptr<EventManager> const&>())
```

Comment: @Neil: Put the `init` in the `class_` parameters like in my example, not in a separate `.def`. Otherwise Boost will assume you have a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot!   Still doesn't work (see updated question), but getting a lot closer.

Comment: @Neil: Try using exactly the same type in `init` as in the constructor, i.e. `shared_ptr<EventManager> const&`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `no_ini`t?  The docs say this is for when you want no constructors, but maybe you can combine it with explicitly asking for one?

```
class_<EventHandle, noncopyable,
    init<boost::shared_ptr<EventManager> const&> >
    ("EventHandle", no_init)
```